# Insert and update database remotely?

Tags: database, vb.net, postgresql

My working environment (`inventory based Software`) is One `Head Office (H.O)` and 4 `Branches`.These 5 application (including `H.O`) have the same database in each application,

All the tables and everything is same in 5 database i.e. identical 5 databases. At present Products, Party etc. will be created only in `H.O` and these items (whatever it is Party or product) will be transferred via email as `XML` to all 4 branches so they can import that `XML` (please note for example we are managing the same id for all tables in all 5 databases i.e. if `product id` is `4005` in `H.O` this should be same in all branches).

What I want is, I need to update or insert without using `XML` sending via email or any other easy method or A centralized database method (i.e. one database for all applications )

The Database is in `PostgreSQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the lines below should work:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb user=postgres password=mypasswd');
```

-- change the connection string to your taste

```
SELECT dblink_exec('INSERT INTO test (some_text) VALUES (''Text go here'');');
```

Where test is a table in the remote database with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id serial
    , some_text text
);
```

After running dblink_exec(), you can check the results in the remote database (or locally, using dblink(), like in the example below).

```
SELECT * FROM dblink('SELECT id, some_text FROM test') AS d(id integer, some_text text);
 id |  some_text
----+--------------
  1 | Text go here
(1 row)
```

You can wrap your dblink_exec call in a function as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dblink_test_update(val text, id integer) RETURNS text AS
$body$
SELECT dblink_exec('UPDATE torles.test SET some_text=' || quote_literal($1) || ' WHERE id = ' || $2);
$body$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

As you can see, you can even build your query string dynamically. (Not that I advocate this approach, since you have to be careful not to introduce a SQL injection vulnerability into your system this way.)

Since dblink_exec returns with a text message about what it did, you have to define your function as RETURNS text unless there are other value-returning statements after the dblink_exec call.

Comment: should i create a function for this ?? what is dblink_connect in your case ??

Comment: dblink_connect() establishes a connection to a remote PostgreSQL database.

Comment: i cant load dblink.when i googled i got this DbLink is located in share/contribs/dblink.sql of your PostgreSQL install.To use it, load the dblink.sql file in the database you would like to use it in. but nothing is there in my directory

Comment: It should be bundled as an extension in 9.1

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html

Comment: am using Postgresql 9.3.3 so With PostgreSQL 9.1 or later, installation of additional modules has been simplified. Registered extensions (including dblink) can be installed with: 'CREATE EXTENSION dblink;'